# How to stop continuous_threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading, pyserial

I am working on a project, where I have to read values from serial port and display them on tkinter GUI. I am using continous threading module of python. I am using a continous thread to read the data on serial port continously after every 0.5s, but now i want to stop this continous thread. So how should I stop it ?
This is the function which I am calling when a checkbutton is presssed

```
def scan():
    print("in scan")
    btn1_state = var1.get()
    print("Scan: %d"%btn1_state)
    t1 = continuous_threading.PeriodicThread(0.5, readserial)
    if(btn1_state == 1):
        t1.start()
    else:
        print("entered else ")
        t1.stop()  #I am using stop() but the thread doesn't stop
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are using a blocking read function in your `readserial` function.  It needs a timeout.  I can reproduce with this code:

```py
import time
import continuous_threading


time_list = []

def save_time():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
    time_list.append(time.time())

th = continuous_threading.PeriodicThread(0.5, save_time)
th.start()

time.sleep(4)
th.join()

print(time_list)
```

This never exits.

Modified from the [examples](https://pypi.org/project/continuous-threading/).

Since continuous_threading expects *it's* event loop to be in control, it never gets to the stop event.